# how can I eliminate the vertical space between div tags?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have these vertically positioned divs, having dynamic content in them, but how to eliminate the spacing between them,
Here is it: http://kbay.in/recent_ads.php

Comment: What `<div>`s? Post your code here.

Comment: `<div>`s don't have a margin (vertical space between them) by default. You've added a `padding` to your `<div>s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things

1. Set the padding to 0px (or remove) for your stylesheet class "ad" in file style.css line 1793 
   change from padding: 10px 5px 10px 0; to padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
2. You also have a hr tag between the divs that gives you some extra space, remove that and you'll have 0px vertical space

Comment: thkns very much,,,,now how do i get rid of that greyish white line,,towards the right of every div,,

Comment: Thats the <hr> tag I mentioned, remove that one too

Comment: i removed it but nthin happened ,,,

Comment: before every <div style="width:810px;margin-left:190px;clear:both;"><div class="ad "  > section there is still a  <hr/> . there might have more than one per ad

Comment: yeah thnx a lot , i got it...thnx very much